# Android-x86 guest in virt-manager screen adjustment

Tags: gnu-screen, virt-manager

[image]I have an MX Linux 19.4 as host and installed Android-x68 9 r2 64bits guest, the problem I'm having is how to adjust the guest screen size to fit the VM screen size, right now the guest screen size is bigger than VM's, and everytime I have to drag the slider to access top/bottom left/right, I'd like Android (guest) to fit the VM screen. Please check the pics.

Comment: Pass `vga=ask` to your guest kernel and change the resolution. IF this doesn't work refer to http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/linux.html#linux

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've seen this trick, I thought it'll change the screen resolution, won't make the guest screen fit the VM's screen. I'll give it a try and see. Thanks for this tip.